# openSSL/openLDAP tls error

Tags: openldap, openssl

I have two `openLDAP` servers, each was setup side by side using a script that did all the heavy lifting, the two servers replicate their configs/users to each other, and for a long time I thought everything was working. Just discovered that one of the servers does not actually negotiate `TLS`, so nothing can authenticate against it.

Both systems are `RHEL 6.7`, both have been updated the exact same time in the exact same way since their creation. Each server should be 100% identical....

Using self signed certificates

If I(on the broken one): `ldapsearch -ZZd 1 -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=org" -w secret-b ""`

```
TLS: loaded CA certificate file /etc/openldap/certs/ca-bundle.crt.
TLS: error: tlsm_PR_Recv returned 0 - error 22:Invalid argument
TLS: error: connect - force handshake failure: errno 22 - moznss error -5938
TLS: can't connect: TLS error -5938:Encountered end of file.
ldap_err2string
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
        additional info: TLS error -5938:Encountered end of file
```

This makes me worry, because I don't believe I should be using Moznss, as I had trouble with the databases in my initial tests, so I'm hard linking to the `ca-bundle.crt`, as well as `server.key` and `server.crt`, Which again, works fine in my other server.

on the other hand, if i:`openssl s_client -connect server1:636 -cert server.crt -key server.key`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140398252824392:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 247 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
```

Which again, on my other server, produces good results, verifying the key.

Both errors, at least based on some searches, hint that it is related to the `moznss` database, but I cant figure out a) Why one is an issue and the other isn't, and b) How to either resolve the issue, or bypass the issue.

If anyone has any further troubleshooting idea's, or potential solutions, i'd be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Verify that the olcTLS*File directives in `cn=config` point to real files.

   ```
   olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.example.com.crt
   olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/pki/tls/private/server.example.com.key
   ```
2. Check your logs. 
   By default CentOS doesn't log for `slapd`. `slapd` defaults to facilty  `LOCAL4` at severity `DEBUG`. You can either edit `/etc/sysconfig/slapd` or your modify syslog configuration.

   ```
   # cat /etc/rsyslog.d/slapd.conf 
   local4.*    /var/log/slapd.log
   ```

   Don't forget to modify `cn=config`'s `olcLogLevel`.
   `olcLogLevel: Config` is probably the most relevant. `man slapd-config` has more details.

Comment: I thought that for ldapsearch the old ldap.conf file overwrote the settings in  the cn=config, so I was using that as a test case... Apparently my ldifs were pointing to moznss still...Weird thing is BOTH serveres were wrong, but one was working anyway. Thank you.